# Use of frobenius map of an elliptic curve

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves, frobenius-groups

I was reading about elliptic curves from https://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/Presentations/WyomingEllipticCurve.pdf. Page No. 44 defines Frobenius map. It defines the frobenius map as $f(x,y)=(x^p,y^p) \mod p$. Isn't it just an identity map by fermat's little theorem? What's the use of this map in elliptic curves?

Comment: Fermat's little theorem says that $x^p = x$ in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p = \mathbb{Z}/p$.  However, this is false for any nontrivial field extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$.  In this case, we are working in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: @Slade I am new to this area. May I know what is a field extension and algebraic closure of $F_p$?

Comment: I'd read Silverman to find out more about the Frobenius map.

Comment: Let $E : y^2 = x^3+x$ then $E(\mathbb{F}_{5^k}) = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{F}_{5^k}, y^2= x^3+x\} \cup \{O \}$, there is a group law on it and the full curve is $\bigcup_k E(\mathbb{F}_{5^k}) = E(\overline{\mathbb{F}_{5}})$. You are supposed to know how to construct those finite fields with $5^k$ elements (and how the Frobenius act on them) and get some intuitions on the roots of "the polynomial map defining $P \mapsto n P, P \in E(\overline{\mathbb{F}_{5}})$"

Answer (score 2):

In the notation of the notes you link to $E(K)$ stands for the points $(x,y)\in K^2$ that satisfy the equation $y^2=x^3 + Ax + b$ that defines the elliptic curve together with the point at infinity. Here $K$ can be any field in which the coefficients $A,B$ are contained. On $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ the Frobenius map $(x,y)\mapsto (x^p,y^p)$ is indeed the identity. But the Frobenius map is defined on $E(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p})$.

So to understand it you first need to understand what $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is. It is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$, i.e. an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ in which every non-constant polynomial has a root. This is an infinite field that contains $\mathbb{F}_p$.

In fact $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the subset of elements in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ that are fixed by the map $x\mapsto x^p$. Hence $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is the subset of elements of $E(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p})$ that are fixed by the Frobenius map.